# Spring-kafka listener concurenncy

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-kafka

I've implemented Kafka consumer using [spring-kafka lib](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka).
I have a Kafka topic with 2 partitions and also I use `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` with concurrency level set to 2 as result every container instance should consume from the single partition in accordance to spring-kafka [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#message-listener-container).

> The KafkaMessageListenerContainer receives all message from all
>   topics/partitions on a single thread. The
>   ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer delegates to 1 or more
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer s to provide multi-threaded consumption.

There is my consumer class:

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {
    private HashMap<String, LinkedBlockingQueue<Event>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}", groupId = "events_group")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Consumer consumer) throws InterruptedException {
        String message = record.value().toString();
        Event event = EventFactory.createEvent(message);
        String customerId = event.getAttributeStringValue(DefinedField.CUSTOMER_ID);
        // add event to hashMap
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Event> queue = hashMap.get(customerId);
        if (queue == null) {
            queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
            queue.add(event);
            hashMap.put(customerId, queue);
        } else {
            queue.add(event);
        }
    }
}
```

As you see I have 'hashMap' collection in that I put my events to a corresponding queue based on message 'customer_id' attribute.
Such functionality requires additional synchronization in case of multiple threads access and as I see spring-kafka creates only one bean instance for all containers, instead of a separate bean instance for each container to avoid concurrency problems.

How can I change this logic programmatically?

I see the only weird way that fixes this problem is to use two JVM's running a separate application with single threaded consumer inside it, as a result access to KafkaConsumer class with #receive method will be single-threaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's correct. That how it works. The Framework relies really not on a bean but just its method to deliver messages to the function.

You may consider to have two `@KafkaListener` methods for each partition in your topic. That's true that records from one partition are delivered to the `@KafkaListener` in a single Thread. So, if you really can't live with that state you may use two `HashMap` for each thread.

The general idea behind that listener abstraction is exactly about *stateless* behavior. That `KafkaConsumer` is the regular Spring *singleton* bean. You have to live with that fact and redesign your solution according this situation.